# Can a library function use a var from a project that depends on it?

Tags: clojure

For example if I have a library `lib` with a function

```
(defn print-name []
  (print config/name))
```

can I write the `config/name` part such that it uses the config var of the project that depends on `lib`?

I have config variables in projects that won't change within the project that I don't want to constantly pass to `lib` functions.

Answer (score 2):

No, this would create a circular dependency. You could work around it with dynamic resolution, but it's likely there's a more idiomatic solution.